# How to solve this problem : maven & intelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

After updating my maven and JDK path to version 14 (I'm on Manjaro), I'm having issues with Maven and IntelliJ on all my projects.

Indeed when I want to run a clean install mvn, I end up with this error message:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-clean-plugin: 2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-clean-plugin: jar : 2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-clean-plugin: pom: 2.5 from / to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): / opt / maven / org /apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom.part.lock (No such file or folder) -> [Help 1]
```

What to do to solve this?
I tried to re-import the Maven dependencies, nothing helps.

Even when creating a new empty Maven project, same message.
My POM.xml does not contain errors.

Thanks

Comment: you maybe need to setup the proxy

Comment: I would delete the contents of the local repository and then try again.

Comment: I do not use a proxy, before updating the maven path everything was fine.

I will try to delete the repository folder

Answer (score 0):

It work, thanks Fabian Meier, just delete the repository folder